# error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, string-interpolation

I have search on the Angular documentation and here on stackoverflow but nothing looks like my issues. I may not have understand something. But my problem is the following :

Angular CLI: 11.0.2
Node: 14.15.1

**My Service :**

```
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  /**
   * Get teams by id
   * @param id 
   * @returns 
   */
   getTeamFromServe(id: number){
    return this.httpClient.get('https://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/'+ id, {
      headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
      },
      observe: 'body',
      responseType: 'text'
    })
  }
}
```

**In my componant :**

**team-details.components.js :**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-team-detail',
  templateUrl: './team-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./team-detail.component.scss']
})
export class TeamDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  arrayTeamInfo: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.apiService.getTeamFromServe(id).subscribe(
      data => {
        let arrayData = [];
        arrayData = JSON.parse(data);
        this.arrayTeamInfo = arrayData;
        console.log(this.arrayTeamInfo);
      }, err => {
        this.arrayTeamInfo = JSON.parse(err.error).message;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**result consol.log :**

```
activeCompetitions: []
address: "null Rio de Janeiro, RJ null"
area: {id: 2032, name: "Brazil"}
clubColors: "Red / Black / White"
crestUrl: "https://crests.football-data.org/1783.svg"
email: null
founded: 1919
id: 1783
lastUpdated: "2020-09-10T02:18:46Z"
name: "CR Flamengo"
phone: null
shortName: "Flamengo"
squad: []
tla: "FLA"
venue: "Estadio Jornalista Mário Filho"
website: "https://www.flamengo.com.br/pagina-inicial-basquete"
```

**team-detail.component.html :**

```
<h1> 
    {{ arrayTeamInfo.name }} 
</h1>
```

This problem occur for each properties like (address, clubColors,email, ...).
And i'm getting this error :
`Error: src/app/teams/team-detail/team-detail.component.html:9:38 - error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'.`

But if i'm doing this on my html file it's working :

```
<h1> 
    {{ arrayTeamInfo['name']}} 
</h1>
```

I've just random this syntax and I don't understand why I have to do this here while in every other componant I have created (with the very same structure) I got no problem...

Have I missing a part or something ?

Comment: `any[]` is the type of an *array* (it's even *named* `array...`), which doesn't have a `name` property. You probably want to loop over the team info objects, read up on `ngFor` in e.g. https://angular.io/tutorial. Or if `arrayTeamInfo['name']` actually *shows* the name, then your types are wrong.

Comment: _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_ ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Also why do you set `responseType: 'text'` then `JSON.parse` the response? The `HttpClient` does that for you by default. I'd strongly recommend reading https://angular.io/guide/http and using a generic type to tell your code what you expect the response to look like, so the rest of your code can be type-safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the component class, you said:

```
arrayTeamInfo: Array<any> = []
```

So `arrayTeamInfo` is definitely going to be an array; its name starts with "array", it's got an array type (`Array<any>` is the same as `any[]`), the default value is an error. Perfectly clear. You reinforce this when receiving data:

```
let arrayData = [];
arrayData = JSON.parse(data);
this.arrayTeamInfo = arrayData;
```

The empty array value is unused, but does set the type of `arrayData` ("array" again!) to `any[]`. This is 100% an array, certainly not going to be *not* an array. Right? But then in the *template*, you do:

```html
<h1> 
    {{ arrayTeamInfo.name }} 
</h1>
```

Arrays don't *have* names, so when the compiler type-checks this it's naturally a little bit confused. Hence the (entirely accurate) error:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
```

In your question you show the team information very much not being an array and say that `arrayTeamInfo['name']` *does* work, so the question is: why did you spend so much time convincing the compiler your value was going to be an array if it's not?

---

So how do you fix it? Firstly, you should express the actual shape of the team information somewhere in your codebase:

```
interface Team {
  name: string;
  area: {id: number; name: string};
  /* ...other props */
}
```

Then you can actually use this when you're fetching the data from the server, so the rest of your code knows what it should be expecting to receive - specify the method's return type, and use the generic type argument to `HttpClient#get` (see https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response):

```
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getTeamFromServe(id: number): Observable<Team> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Team>(  // <- set this
      `https://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/${id}`,
      { 
        headers: {'X-Auth-Token': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'},
        /* other options restated defaults or were wrong */
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Finally, in your component, the type of the property should actually reflect what you're planning to assign to it, so the compiler can check that what you've written makes sense:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-team-detail',
  templateUrl: './team-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./team-detail.component.scss']
})
export class TeamDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  teamInfo?: Team;  // <- no initial value, so undefined until request completes

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.apiService.getTeamFromServe(id).subscribe(data => {
      this.teamInfo = data;  // <- data is typed as Team, so the compiler's happy
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> 
    {{ teamInfo?.name }}
    <!-- safe navigation handles undefined default --> 
</h1>
```

*(Note that the component no longer needs to `JSON.parse` the data from the service - the point of having a separate service is to abstract away the details of the transport layer from the presentation layer, so having something like "we're getting data as a JSON string" leak into the component isn't helpful.)*

Another option is to lean more into observables, using the `| async` pipe rather than needing safe navigation; I wrote about that [on my blog](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html) a few years ago (using the old `Http` syntax, but the ideas are still useful).